# Can this be a presentation of cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Non-trivial group $\langle a,b \mid aba^{-1}b^{-1},a^m,b^n,a^hb^k \rangle$ where $h,k,m,n$ are different positive integers and are not 1. It seems not a cyclic group, but I can't give a proof.(Also, the cases that h,k are larger than m,n respectively are meaningless) Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: The cases with $h\ge m,k\ge n$ aren't meaningless, they're just redundant.

Comment: @arctictern Some one asked me to add.

Comment: $m=8,n=4,h=3,k=2$ gives a cyclic group of order $4$.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank you, can I say it can be cyclic off we can get a equation that a=b^t, or b=a^d?

Comment: I don't think so. Another example is $m=4, n=6, h=2, k=3$, which is cyclic of order $12$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not for all choices of $m,n,h,k$.

If $m=12, n=3, h=8, k=4$, then this group is $C_{12}$, which is cyclic.

If $m=2, n=3, h=4, k=6$, then this group is $C_2 \times C_3 \cong C_{6}$, which is cyclic.

If $m=5, n=7, h=2, k=3$, then this group is trivial, which is cyclic.

Comment: Thank you, but I mean the general case, I think it can never be cyclic .

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add h,k can not be 1.

Comment: Sorry, but h=8 is meaningless, since it's just the case of h=4

Comment: It'd be interesting to know the exact conditions on $m,n,h,k$ for that presentation to be cyclic, including the trivial group.

Comment: Sorry, I think there is a problem, k=4 is just the case of k =1, which violated my assumption.

Comment: Actually, the cases that h,k are larger than m,n are meaningless

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel sorry, I think I just mean the non-trivial case. I apologize, sorry.

Comment: I don't think the cases in which $h$ and $k$ are larger than $m$ and $n$ are meaningless — they're just equivalent to other cases with $h < m$ and $k < n$.  For example, if the relations are $a^3 = e$, $b^4 = e$, and $a^4 b^5 = e$, then this would be equivalent to saying that $a^3 = e$, $b^4 = e$, and $ab = e$.  (Which would, I think, lead to the trivial group.)